# Problem with datagrid view button column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Could anyone please help with this?

I have a DataGridView with three columns and one button column.

If I click on the button column, then all values in that row should be transferred to another form.

Note : I have already implemented the following click event handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Is there an alternative other than using the cell click event?

Many Thanks.....

Comment: question is not clear, no question mark and not well defined issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the CellContentClick event.

> This event occurs when the cell content is clicked. It also occurs when the user presses and releases the SPACEBAR while a button cell or check box cell has focus, and will occur twice for these cell types if the cell content is clicked while pressing the SPACEBAR.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx

Edit: The CellContentClick event provides a DataGridViewCellEventArgs parameters, which contains the exact column and row clicked. From that link I provided, I can put together a short example. I'm assuming the values you want to pass are strings and are in columns 2, 3 and 4 (indexes 1, 2 and 3, respectively). *Note, this isn't tested!*

```
if (DataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && cellEvent.RowIndex != -1)
{
    DataRow currRow = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    SendValuesSomewhereElse(Convert.ToString(currRow[1]), Convert.ToString(currRow[2]), Convert.ToString(currRow[3]));
}
```

Comment: how to find the button cell in datagrid view and want to get the corresponding row values also...would you pls elaborate your answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have first three columns with data and then the fourth column with the button.

A quick and dirty way to extract the data is:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //If not fourth column then return (the button)
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 3)
        return;
    object col1 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    object col2 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
    object col3 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
}
```

You get the clicked row with `e.RowIndex` and clicked column with `e.ColumnIndex`. 0 being first row/column.